# weightloss vs fatloss

Tags: bodybuilding, calories, body-fat, home-exercise

*I am 24 years old, 62.35 kg in weight,and 5 feet 6 inch in height* I have been working out daily at home, mainly cardiovascular workout from top rated app.

I want to grow a good fitness, a bit of abs, wide shoulder, good biceps and triceps. For this I am checking my calorie intake and keeping it within 2200 calories everyday for last few months.

As a result I am seeing few changes in my fitness but I lost weight from 65ks to 62.35 kg; but my goal was to lose fat not weight. I want to keep the weight but lose the fat.

**Should not I be concerned with the weight loss? What should I do to keep this weight at around 62-65 but grow muscular?**

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time for a full answer, but look into bodyweight exercises you can do in the home, http://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness is pretty good, plus there are some good answers on here that cover bodyweight fitness. Don't adjust your diet, start doing bodyweight training, then after you've been doing that for a month, reassess your diet and see where you are.

Answer (score 2):

> I have been working out daily at home, mainly cardiovascular workout from top rated app.
>
> I want to grow a good fitness, a bit of abs, wide shoulder, good biceps and triceps. For this I am checking my calorie intake and keeping it within 2200 calories everyday for last few months.

None of this will be accomplished just by eating and doing cardio. If you want bigger muscles, you need to lift heavy things.

> As a result I am seeing few changes in my fitness but I lost weight from 65ks to 62.35 kg; but my goal was to lose fat not weight. I want to keep the weight but lose the fat.

If you've lost fat, it means you're spending more calories than you are taking in. It could be because you need to eat more, or because your calorie counting is inaccurate.

> Should not I be concerned with the weight loss? What should I do to keep this weight at around 62-65 but grow muscular?

I would be slightly concerned, yes, but that's because I'm 187cm. For me, that would be dramatically underweight. You didn't mention your height though. If you're pretty short, it could be ok. If you're around my height, you should be aiming for at least 75+ kgs in my opinion.

Comment: how long should i keep on eating in calorie deficit? FYI I want to lose the fat but keep the weight.

Comment: I dont know I have lost fat or not, I just know I lost weight.

Comment: Depends on the individual but @Md.SifatulIslam should use this as a guide for "optimal weight" https://symmetricstrength.com/calculator/ideal_bodyweight

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have calculated the wrong calorie content of the food you are taking or your metabolism is high which is burning all the calories you are taking. As you have mentioned you workout mostly consist of cardiovascular activities this will also be burning some more calories.

If you want to grow muscles then working out in home following some app wont be of much help to you. I would suggest you to join a gym and start lifting. To build muscle you have to strain them so that muscle fiber gets microscopic tear up and then feed them with protein.

At 5 feet 6 weight in between 65-70 will be ideal for you. As you are on 62.35 you need to gain 5 kg and that should be lean muscle mass. For that you need to make sure that your macros are correct. You should get protein per pound of your muscle mass so all your diet for a day combined together should have approx 150g of protein.

Having abs depends on you body fat percentage. The better muscle mass you will have and the lower your body fat percentage will be, you abs will be more visible.